# Make VNC available without opening non-ssh ports to the WAN

Tags: networking, linux-networking, remote-access

I have a local network consisting of a gateway router/firewall running dd-wrt, a machine running OS X called mac, and a Debian host named ssh-server.  The firewall forwards port 22 to ssh-server.

I would like to make VNC on mac available outside the local network with only the SSH port on ssh-server opened to the WAN.  In other words, I do not want to configure the firewall to forward ports to mac:5900 or open any other ports.  Is this possible?  How?

I have a remote access solution, but it requires opening another port.  It uses ssh tunnelling between ssh-server and mac (see below for details).  However, I don't like this solution because I need to open another port to the WAN, and it unnecessarily uses a secure protocol on the LAN.

What I've done is:
ssh-server$ ssh -nNT -L *:12345:mac:5900 user@mac

Then set up the firewall to forward port 12345 to ssh-server:12345.

Finally, from the WAN I use ssh port forwarding to connect to wan:12345.

However, I don't like that this solution leaves port 12345 open on the WAN and forwarded to VNC.

Comment: I am not sure why you would opening anything on your firewall after you setup an SSH tunnel. You shouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
remote-client% ssh firewall-port22-which-goes-to-ssh-server -L 5900:mac:5900
```

followed by

```
remote-client% vncviewer localhost:5900
```

Comment: That did it.  I'm somewhat embarrassed that I didn't know a ssh tunnel could... tunnel... through to another host.

Comment: I rather figured you didn't, but it seemed rude to presume.  Glad we could help - `ssh` really does a *ton* of useful stuff, the man pages are well worth a lengthy perusal.